# Validación de un correo electrónico en C usando el método 'strchr'

Tags: c, string

Necesito implementar una acción en C con la cabecera

```
bool check_mail( const char *mail );
```

Y debo utilizar el método `strchr( )` para su realización. En principio bastaría validar una dirección tipo `<string> @ <string>.<string>` sin más.

Serían válidas:user@uoc.edu, name.surname@uoc.edu, user@eimt.uoc.edu 
Pero no user.uoc.edu, user@uoc. user@uoc.

He estado mirando y hay muchas maneras de validar un correo pero en casi todas se utilizan expresiones regulares y/o bucles `for( )` sencillamente buscando el carácter y listos.

Ando bastante perdido al respecto. La idea que tenía era hacer algo tipo

```
bool check_mail( const char *mail ) {
  // PR1 EX4
  //Validate pre conditions
  assert( mail != NULL );

  char email[40];

  strcpy( email, mail );

  const char check = '@';
  const char checkPoint = '.';
  char *check1;
  char *check2;

  check1 = strchr( email, check );
  check2 = strchr( email, checkPoint );

  //If all is OK
  return true;
}
```

y, a partir de los dos punteros, validar si existe el formato deseado....pero me pierdo, estoy empezando y me quedo bloqueado.

Alguna ayuda o sugerencia? Por más que miro aquí o en Google, encuentro muchas cosas en otros lenguajes, pero nada en C y menos mediante el uso de punteros y `strschr( )`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es mas fácil que todo lo que estás haciendo.

> #### char *strchr( const char *s, int c );
>
> ### DESCRIPTION
>
> The `strchr( )` function returns a pointer to the first occurrence of the character c in the string s.
>
> ### RETURN VALUE
>
> return a pointer to the matched character or NULL if the  character  is  not  found.

En traducción libre, viene a decir que la función `strchr( )` busca un caracter en la cadena; si lo encuentra, devuelve un puntero a dicho caracter. Si no lo encuentra, develve `NULL`.

Por lo tanto, nos bastaría con hacer:

```
bool check_mail( const char *mail ) {
  mail = strchr( mail, '@' );

  if( mail == NULL ) return false;

  return strchr( mail, '.' ) != NULL;
}
```

Aquí nos aprovechamos de que en C, las variables se pasan **por copia**; podemos modificar **cualquier** argumento dentro de la función, que no afectará para nada a la versión de fuera.

Como ves, nos limitamos a *avanzar* el *puntero* `mail`. Lo avanzamos hasta el primer `'@'`. Si no lo encuentra, pues ya podemos parar y devolver `false` directamente.

Si lo encontramos, pues buscamos **a partir de donde estamos**, es decir, **a partir del primer `'@'`** un caracter `'.'`.

Como no hay que buscar mas cosas, pues ya sabemos seguro lo que vamos a devolver: si encontramos el `'.'`, entonces el retorno de `strchr( )` **no será igual a `NULL`**, es decir, la expresión será `true`. Mientras que si no lo encontramos, `strchr( )` devolverá `NULL`, con lo que la expresión `strchr( ) != NULL` será `false`.

Con lo que podemos devolver el resultado de la expresión directamente :-)

Answer (score 0):

Esta parte es sin strchar, pero tambien le puede servir a alguien.

```
int validar_email(char *email){

    char copia[100] = "";
    int i = 0, errores = 0, punto = 0, arroba = 0;


    strcpy(copia, email);

    int g = strlen(copia);

    if( g < 5){

        printf("1\n");
        return 1;

    }

    if(copia[g-1] == '.'){
        printf("2\n");
        return 1;
    }

    if(copia[0] == '.' || copia[0] == '@'){
        printf("3\n");
        errores++;
        return errores;
    }

    while(copia[i] != '\0'){

        if(copia[i] >= 'a' && copia[i] <= 'z'){
            printf("4\n");
            i++;
        }
        else if(copia[i] >= 'A' && copia[i] <= 'Z'){
            printf("5\n");
            i++;
        }
        else if(copia[i] >= '0' && copia[i] <= '9'){
            printf("6\n");
            i++;
        }
        else if(copia[i] == '.'){
            printf("7\n");

            if(arroba == 0){
                printf("8\n");
                errores ++;
                return errores;
            }

            i++;
            punto++;

        }
        else if(copia[i] == '@'){

            printf("9\n");

            if(punto != 0){

                printf("10\n");
                errores++;
                return errores;
            }

            i++;
            arroba++;
        }
        else{
            printf("11\n");
            errores++;
            return errores;
        }

        
    }

    if(errores != 0 || arroba != 1 || punto != 1 ){
        printf("12\n");
        return 1;
    }
    printf("13\n");

    return errores;
}
```